# How to correct organize olap-cub

Tags: business-intelligence, olap, cubes

Could you suggest me way to organize nice olap-cube?

It's about sales (standard fields product, customer, region, etc.).
Some of products **always** measured by values, but other by volume. Can i use same field for both and separate by another field (var or vol). Or better make different field for each measure.

I use [Cubes](http://cubes.databrewery.org/) python framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'd favour making a different field for each measure, and also adding a dimension for the unit type anyway.